# Whats wrong with that code?

Tags: java

I have a problem with the following code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;    

public class Fraktalz extends Applet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Graphics grafika;   

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    smok(200,360,500,120,20);


}


public void smok(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int iteracja){
    if (iteracja == 0){
        grafika.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    } else{
        int cx = (x1 + x2) / 2;
        int cy = (y1 + y2) / 2;

        int x3 = cx + (y2 - cy);
        int y3 = cy + (x2 - cx);

        smok(x1,y1,y3,y3,iteracja-1);
        smok(x2,y2,x3,y3, iteracja-1);
    }
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Fraktalz();

        }
    });
}
}
```

It says I got a `nullPointerException` at `Graphics grafika;`
When I've done:

```
Fraktalz fr = new Fraktalz();
Graphics grafika = fr.getGraphics();
```

I got an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Class.getClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Panel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Panel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.applet.Applet.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Fraktalz.<init>(Fraktalz.java:6)
    at Fraktalz.<init>(Fraktalz.java:9)
    at Fraktalz.<init>(Fraktalz.java:9)
```

Can somebody help me with that error?

Comment: If this is an applet, it shouldn't be run with a main() method.

Comment: where is the Fraktalz constructor? since you didnt initialize the grafika it will be null.

Answer (score 4):

Create a constructor and initialize grafika there:

```
public class Fraktalz extends Applet{
    public Fraktalz() {
        grafika = getGraphics();
    }
}
```

I assume that you tried to initialize it like this:

```
public class Fraktalz extends Applet{
    Fraktalz fr = new Fraktalz();
    Graphics grafika = fr.getGraphics();

    ...
}
```

This causes a `StackOverflow` since you are creating an instance of `Fraktalz`, which causes its `fr` member to initialize by creating an `Fraktalz` instance, which again causes its `fr` member to ... That leads to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably an infinite recursion. paint() calls smok(). smok() calls either smok() or drawLine(). drawLine() calls paint() again...

Comment: Good catch, but the `StackOverflow` exception stack trace does not show the `smoke()` method, instead it shows the `Fraktalz` default constructor only